# How send multiple command as input in a program?

Tags: shell, command-line, input

I know how send a command as a input in a program like this:

```sh
echo toto | ./my_prog
```

And with process substitution + redirection:

```sh
r < <(echo toto)
```

But how to do this if I want to input a second or a third input?

For example, I have a program that ask my username first and after this it ask me others informations like a number phone or whatever in different input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `{` and `}` to collect the output of multiple programs. For instance, `{ echo one; echo two; } |program`. Leave a space after `{` and before `}` and ensure there is a semicolon after the last command within the braces.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells)

```
./my_proc << END_OF_INPUTS
username
phone number
whatever
END_OF_INPUTS
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use printf and a pipe too

```
printf "%s\n" "username" "number phone" "whatever" | ./my_prog
```

Comment: I can use python too like this: `python -c 'print "toto\x0Atutu\x0A\x0A5\x0A"' | ./my_prog`

Comment: Seems a bit of overkill to spawn python just for this. `printf` is a shell builtin.